# how to read images in python based upon alphabet characters of images files in folder?

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision

i have  files in folder as waqas.jpg,waqas2.jpg,umar1.jpg,umar2.jpg. I want to create two lists as waqas and umar and then add the other files based upon prefix matches.How can we do this general in python to pick from path and divide into groups based upon alphabet categories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listdir()` to get all the files under a folder and then use the regex module `re` to match filenames:

```py
import os
import re

path_to_folder = "./"   # change this to be the path to your folder

files = os.listdir(path_to_folder)

waqas = []
umar = []

for file in files:
  if os.path.isfile(file):
    basename = os.path.basename(file)
    if re.match("^waqas*", basename):
      waqas.append(file)
    elif re.match("^umar*", basename):
      umar.append(file)
```

and then you can read all the files in the two lists separately.

If you want to make it more general (i.e. more than 2 groups) you can do something like this:

```py
import os
import re

path_to_folder = "./"   # change this to be the path to your folder

files = os.listdir(path_to_folder)

files_by_prefix = {
  "waqas": [],
  "umar": [],
  "someOtherPrefix": [],
}

for file in files:
  if os.path.isfile(file):
    basename = os.path.basename(file)
    for key in files_by_prefix.keys():
      if re.match("^{}*".format(key), basename):
        files_by_prefix[key].append(file)
        break
```

so if you want to add more prefixes, just add an item to the dict

Answer (score 0):

Another option, simpler and less powerful than using regex:

```
import os

path_to_folder = "./"   # change this to be the path to your folder
files = os.listdir(path_to_folder)

waqas_files = [f for f in files if f.startswith('waqas')]
umar_files = [f for f in files if f.startswith('umar')]
```

You can also check if some specific string is part of the file name (not just at the beginnig). It is more generic but depending on the actual string you are trying to match, may get false positives:

```
waqas_files = [f for f in files if 'waqas' in f]
```